# bower - fatal: unable to connect to github.com

Tags: github, bower

After upgrading ember-cli on my mac (Yosemite 10.10.2)

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli
npm cache clean
bower cache clean
npm install -g ember-cli@0.1.12
....
```

or maybe after Yosemite upgrade to 10.10.2,
or after upgrade my Java to v8-32...
my bower doesnt work anymore.

If I try:

```
bower list
```

I get an error:

```
bower check-new Checking for new versions of the project dependencies..
bower ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Operation timed out
```

But if I execute:

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader.git
```

it works:

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader.git
c6006a11515c756d115bb5209103a22c2e9554a0 refs/heads/master
929777f8b5c60db3120712c7328f5debdf74a0cd refs/tags/0.0.1
055d50f770ad333e7ead10ecb04605f951e2435b refs/tags/0.0.2
9defa2c59df38dcc334d6c1cc266075c04c2a4f6 refs/tags/0.0.3
a925b8fc428829ea3599e66eb0e6353726426356 refs/tags/0.0.4
c6006a11515c756d115bb5209103a22c2e9554a0 refs/tags/v0.1.0
```

Also every git clone git:// or http:// works and I can access 192.30.252.128 over http.

Only in combination with bower it doesnt work.
With npm I have also no problems.

What Im trying was to uninstall and reinstall bower. But this doesnt solve the problem.

Next try:

```
.bowerrc
```

with:

```
{
   "directory": "bower_components",
   "analytics": false,
   "proxy": "",
   "https-proxy": ""
}
```

Next try:

```
.gitconfig

[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

With the result:

```
Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Iam also try:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

to add github.com under known_hosts.

The strange thing is:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Try it again:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi xxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So sometimes it works and sometimes not. A look at https://status.github.com/ 
shows that everything is fine from github.

But why I get sometimes a timeout?
Maybe a DNS Server lag? Every other connections are fine.

Also a ping is looking fine:
The badest time was

```
time=100.173 ms
```

over minutes and I start parallel the bower install command with same timeout as before.... but the ping was going on and only with 100ms.

Im also exit my firewalls with no result.

I have no proxy configurred.

Any idea?

**Update 09/02/2014**

Im currently in Hamburg and here, the bower install works fine. So it is not a problem of my system installation.

**Update 12/02/2014**

After being back at home, it also works without any changes. 
Strange!

Comment: OSX -- Having same issue behind a proxy (I guess). Search that error in Google and you'll see a lot in the bower git issues.

Answer (score 11):

From this npm thread: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5257#issuecomment-60441477

Try dumping the following into your .gitconfig

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[url "https://github.com"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com
```

Since I'm on a Windows machine, I also had to ensure that `c:\users\me\.gitconfig` and the one on my modified home drive `h:\.gitconfig` were the same.

Comment: This resolved my problem. Thanks! I am using Mac OS X, and added this snippet to the end of the file ~/.gitconfig

Comment: Thanks a lot this one is solved my problem, tried many solution but couldn't helped.

Answer (score 8):

Run

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

saves lot of pain specially if one is behind the firewall.

Answer (score 4):

### One Solution for Requiring Modules

This solution has not been tested against `bower list`, however, (like in my situation) you may be impeded to `bower install`s due to local, environmental policies. Here's what allowed me to leverage Bower -- saving me from a multitude of headaches:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js",
    "jquery": "https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.4",
    "moment": "https://github.com/moment/moment.git",
    "underscore": "https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#~1.8.3"
}
...
```

OR,

`bower install https://domain.ext/path/to/asset.ext -S`

You may be getting the error, `fatal: unable to connect to github.com:` while trying to install -- this is because *in some environments bower cannot resolve the `git://` protocol*. However, it will resolve `http(s):`.

My suggestion:

- Search Bower for a package,
- Navigate to the git repository,
- Copy the **https** git clone URI,
- `bower install https://.../author/module.git --save`

This will *save* (`--save` / `-S`) the package to your `bower.json` file with the `#~n.n.n` notation for the package-version.

Hope this helps you guys as it did I.